# Return a reference to a Armadillo vector element

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am having a hard time determining how to return a reference to an element of an armadillo vector.

e.g.

```
arma::vec3 v = arma::zeros(3);
v.at(0) = 1; // works as expected, surely this means the at() method returns a reference?
```

however this does not compile:

```
struct Custom {
  arma::vec3 v;
  double& x() { return v.at(0) }
}
Custom custom;
custom.x() = 1;
```

The error is as follows:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘double&’ from expression of type ‘const double’

I assume this is because at() returns a copy instead of a reference, but then how does the previous example work?

I believe this may be because of armadillo's glue types that are returned rather than a real 'double', but I can't find any documentation on these so I'm unsure how to use them.

---

**Answer**

The below methods work, giving 'reference-like' named access to the vector elements.

```
inline double x() const { return at(0); }
inline double& x() { return at(0); }

inline double y() const { return at(1); }
inline double& y() { return at(1); }

inline double z() const { return at(2); }
inline double& z() { return at(2); }

inline const arma::subview_col<double> xy() const { return rows(0,1); }
inline arma::subview_col<double> xy() { return rows(0,1); }
```

Comment: You've made `x()` const in the second case. Either lose the `const` after `x()`, or add one after `arma::vec3`. (Or you may want to provide both versions.)

Comment: Ah of course! Excellent! It appears to be working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at(0)` is almost certainly returning a *proxy object*, which can be converted to `double`, or be assigned a `double`, but is not actually a reference. This may be to avoid dangling references, or to allow for efficient storage of sparse matrices. The [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) for Armadillo is unfortunately pretty quiet on the semantics, but it does not specify that `at` returns a reference.

This would suggest that you are discouraged from returning a reference. Is there another way to achieve what you want?

Comment: I'm aware of Armadillo's proxy objects, and you're correct in that their documentation for them is lacking so I'm uncertain on their capabilities. I guess my primary objective was to have a named version of the at() method, so that instead of v.at(0) = 1; I can have v.x() = 3; I guess I could have a getter and setter, but I don't see why I'd need to if v.at(0) = 1 can work.

Comment: You could always return the glue type that `at` returns - perhaps using `auto` or `decltype` to avoid hardcoding the precise type.

Comment: I'd love to know what the glue type is! I've been trying to use auto and decltype for a while now, haha but I can't use decltype with member functions as the instance isn't in scope when in the trailing return type. Having trouble getting the right syntax.

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<arma::vec3>().at(0))` might help. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Comment: I did try that, I get this error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘double&’ from expression of type ‘const double’. Pointing at the "return v.at(0)" call. I don't understand how there could be type differences when I'm using auto :/

Comment: Turns out the const function modifier was actually the root problem all along, I've updated my answer to avoid using decltype as it is simpler.